# Show that there are $36$ $5$-Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> Given the symmetric group $S_6$, we consider a $5$-Sylow subgroup. How can one show that this subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z}$? I have to show that there exist $36$ such subgroups. How can I do that?

What I know:

- If $G$ is a finite group, $|G|=p^n \cdot m $, where $p$ is prime, $n\ge 1$ and $(p,m)=1$, then a Sylow $p$-group in $G$ is a subgroup $H\subset G$, where $|H|=p^n$
- The number of distinct Sylow-$p$-groups in $G$ is congruent to $1\mod p$
- The number of distinct Sylow-$p$-groups in $G$ is a divisor of $m$.

Comment: Same comment as in you other [recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/403204/11619):   
You probably also know several things about conjugation in symmetric groups. If not, then you should refresh that before you tackle this problem. Bits from that earlier material will come in handy here!

Comment: Regarding your first question: Could a Sylow 5-group in $S_6$ have $5^2$ elements? Or $5^3$? Following up: How many different groups of order $5$ do you know?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, because somebody else already did. I do not approve of the practice of asking two obviously closely related question in the span of three minutes, though. You obviously spent zero time digesting the answers to the other question before tackling this. The questions are probably from some textbook (it is somewhat unlikely, but not impossible, that they would come from the same homework set). In fact I find this a bit easier, but may be I missed an easier solution to the other :-)

Comment: Well, I take back some of that. I think that you should have asked this question before the other, but you probably no way of foreseeing that. I apologize for that. But, yeah, you can't do these without a bit of combinatorics (not too tough, though).

Comment: You are clearly trying to get a feel for how Sylow subgroups work, and how they relate to the particular context of $S_6$, where the group order has prime factors $2, 3, 5$. This will depend not only on the Sylow theorems themselves, which apply to all finite groups, but on the structure of the concrete group you happen to be dealing with. So you can expect that your knowledge of $S_6$ will be relevant to the answer. One important aspect of the Sylow theorems which you have not quoted is that all the Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate to each other (for fixed p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group. Since $|S_6|=6!$ contains only one factor of $5$, and a Sylow 5-group must have order a power of $5$, the $5$-group must have order $5$. Since any group of prime order is cyclic, we see the $5$-group is $\mathbb Z/ 5\mathbb Z$.

So the subgroup must be generated by one element, a $5$-cycle. And since all $5$-cycles are conjugate, and all Sylow $5$-groups are conjugate, the problem reduces to counting the number of $5$-cycles in $S_6$, and then dividing by $4$ to account for the fact that there are $4$ in each subgroup.

Comment: There are four 5-cycles in each subgroup.

Comment: @MarkBennet Indeed. Mistake corrected.